# How to draw Pie chart like below by using coreplot?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-plot

How to draw Pie chart like below by using coreplot???[image]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but... Consider using something other than a pie chart. They're over-used and often the wrong choice for presenting data. Discussion here: http://www.quora.com/How-and-why-are-pie-charts-considered-evil-by-data-visualization-experts (and lot of other places if you google for 'pie chart evil' or similar).

Comment: The pie chart image you use as an example is a pretty good example of when a pie chart just takes up space without being useful. All the data items are of a very similar size -- in which case, a bar chart would be much more suitable. And with a pie chart, you've separated the item and its size (in text) from the actual identifier (key). Why bother obfuscating in this way? Use a bar chart or something else!

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use two pie charts to draw this—one for the inner ring and another one for the outer ring. Look at the Donut Chart plot in the Plot Gallery example app.

The `pieRadius` sets the radius of the outside of the ring and the `pieInnerRadius` property sets the inner radius. Use a negative `labelOffset` to put the labels inside the plot. Insert a newline ('\n') character between the word and the number to make the two-line labels for the inner plot. Set the `textAlignment` of the label text style to `CPTTextAlignmentCenter` to center align the multi-line labels.

You can use the default color scheme for the pie slices, but it only has 10 colors. If you want more or different slice colors, implement the `-sliceFillForPieChart:recordIndex:` datasource method and return the desired fill (which can be a color, gradient, or image) for each slice.

Answer (score 0):

> http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/pie-chart-drawing-in-iphone-using-core-plot-library.html
>
> I hope It Will Help ful to you

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) for you to include the essential parts of the linked article in your answer, and provide the link for reference. Failing to do that leaves the answer at risk from link rot.